# Fill the gaps between two text fields when hiding other fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, layout

I have some text fields in a form page:

```
 acquiredThroughLone.text=[acquitionArray objectAtIndex:row];
assetsTypeApprectitiveorDepriciateTxtFld.text=[appriciateArray objectAtIndex:row];
purchasedOrGirftTextFld.text=[purchaseArray objectAtIndex:row];
 assetsCategoryTextFld.text=[assetsCategorySplitDisplayArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

When I am hiding some of the fields with

```
[assetsTypeApprectitiveorDepriciateTxtFld setHidden:YES];
[purchasedOrGirftTextFld setHidden:YES];
```

I am getting gaps between the remaining text fields. How can I fill the gaps?

Comment: are you using auto layout or autresizing in your cell class

Comment: if u r giving support of only i-Os9 then use stackView  which is automatically manage space if u hide any textfield . stackView set height =0 when any view hide. for i_Os8 and i_os 7 u need to manually manage height when view hide.

Comment: i am using auto layout in form page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get all textFields IBOutlet height constraints 
(Don't Use TextFields Border Style default)**

[image]

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *text1HeightConstraints;

if([acquitionArray objectAtIndex:row] != nil)
{
   self.text1HeightConstraints.constant=30;
   acquiredThroughLone.text=[acquitionArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
 else
{
    self.text1HeightConstraints.constant=0;
}
```

Comment: while i am doing like this..if ([acquiredThroughLone.text isEqualToString:@"N"])
    {
        self.enterLenderNameHeightConstraints=0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.enterLenderNameHeightConstraints=30;
    }
error like this constant is,incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning from UITextfiled to int

Comment: please write like  self.enterLenderNameHeightConstraints.constant=0;

Comment: i wrote like this ..self.enterLenderNameHeightConstraints.constant=0;,but it shows error like this: property ' constant ' not found on object type of UITextField

Comment: i wrote like this ..self.enterLenderNameHeightConstraints.constant=0;,but it shows error like this: property ' constant ' not found on object type of UITextField

Comment: don't create UITextField outlet create NSLayoutConstraint outlet of this UITextField which is shown in how to create in answer image. It look like  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *text1HeightConstraints;